# Time travel story where the hero repeatedly tries to save a woman using government time machine

Tags: story-identification, tv, time-travel

The hero apparently works at a government facility and repeatedly tried to save a woman from her abusive husband. In one of the iterations a policeman was also killed along with the woman. In the last iteration he overloads the time machine into destruction to send him further back, finally allowing him to save her.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Almost certainly [Retroactive](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117468/).  Synopsis: "A psychiatrist makes multiple trips through time to save a woman that was murdered by her brutal husband."

Comment: Thanks Kyle ^^ Finally I can try to watch it again.